# How would i make the solar eclipse a monthly occurrence?

Tags: orbital-mechanics

**How would i make the solar eclipse a monthly occurrence?**

I'm going to try and put the solar eclipse into a creatures life cycle, so how could I make it a monthly occurrence?

Comment: Frequent solar eclipses have already been discussed https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/173961/30492

Comment: Astronomy is not my forte, but I am not sure that solar and lunar eclipses are sufficiently similar to see questions about them as duplicates. There are also no answers to the proposed duplicate question that could be used to answer this question.

Comment: @Otkin, my answer https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/173964/30492 precisely answer this question

Comment: @L.Dutch Sorry, I missed your answer.

Comment: @L.Dutch Also, forgot to ask, is your described scenario the only possible solution for this particular question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the moon to be the right size and have an orbital inclination of exactly 0°, so that it passes directly in front of the sun on every orbit. It’s unlikely, but not impossible. It probably won’t stay with that exact inclination over geological timescales, though, especially if there are other planets in the solar system, so it’s hard to see how animals could evolve life cycles built around it.

Comment: Agree.. orbital inclination is important, and it will occur when the moon is very big, or very close to the planet, you'd get a monthly eclipse easily.